# Who are all the agents and where can I find them?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

During my travels, I occasionally meet someone who wants to join the Inquisition and I can gain them as an agent. There isn't usually a quest marker or anything that goes along with them (sometimes there is like the one in the Dalish camp but not most of them).

Who are all the agents and where can I find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is a list of all the agents discovered so far.](http://www.reddit.com/r/dragonage/comments/2nh1n6/list_of_agents_spoilers/)

Most agents are not missable, but there are a few to be aware of. Belle in Val Royeaux must be recruited when you first go Val Royeaux or she will be gone in later visits. Speaker Anais has been reported to be missable, but this most likely can be chalked up to the dialogue tree (you must select "Spread word of the Inquisition" to recruit her as an agent). Florianne requires a specific outcome and following judgement in the Wicked Hearts, Wicked Eyes story quest. The Sky Watcher can only be recruited during your first visit to the Fallow Mire.

Comment: I definitely recruited the Sky Watcher after visiting the Fallow Mire many times. I did recruit him on the visit I first met him on.